# What is causing my Java `.matches()` regex to return False?

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to find the occurrences of the `{` character in a string.

Given the string `String a = "  {";`, why does `a.matches("\\{")` return False?

I'm trying to follow the guide here: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm . It looks like the Simple Matching section should do just what I need. But it doesn't seem to behave as expected. I cannot seem to detect either the `tab` or `{` characters.

I've tried things like `.matches("\\s*\\{")` to try and account for the tabs befor the curly, but it still fails; even trying to just match the tab, which is the very first character in the string reports false with the expression `.matches("\\s")`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `a.matches(" *\\{")` instead (or `a.matches("( \\t)*\\{")` to handle tabs and spaces).  I believe `String.matches()` checks to see if the *entire* string matches the given pattern.  If your string has leading whitespace that is not accounted for in your regex, it will not match.

Comment: Edit:  that second one should actually be `a.matches("[ \\t]*\\{")`.  Here's a runnable example - http://ideone.com/2NsqH

Comment: @aroth "checks to see if the entire string matches the given pattern." Righto. That explains the failure! Your example works perfectly. I wish I could checkmark your comment as the correct one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try it out this way.............

```
String s = "{1,23,abc{{ { {abc";

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^(a-zA-Z0-9)\\s]*?\\{[^(a-zA-Z0-9)\\s]*?");

Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);

String datu = new String();

    while(mat.find()){


        System.out.println(mat.group());
    }
```